# How to get the product in a Array<Model> using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have a Array,like:

```
{
    "10-08": [
        { 
            "Items": [
                {
                    "RoomNum": 2
                }
            ], 
            "Dates": {
                "From": "2019-10-03T16:00:00.000Z",
                "To": "2019-10-08T16:00:00.000Z"
            } 
        }
    ],
    "10-09":[
        { 
            "Items": [
                {
                    "RoomNum": 3
                }
            ], 
            "Dates": {
                "From": "2019-10-07T16:00:00.000Z",
                "To": "2019-10-11T16:00:00.000Z"
            } 
        }
    ],
```

the `differenceInDays`   is from `date-fns.js`

now, i want get

```
(items.RoomNum  * differenceInDays(item.TravelDates.To,item.TravelDates.From))
+(items.RoomNum  * differenceInDays(item.TravelDates.To,item.TravelDates.From))...
and so on.
```

For example：
i want get:

```
2*5   +3*4
```

how can i do?

Comment: You should start with a `differenceInDays` function, as you've laid out here. Once you've got that, iterate over each element you want to sum up and just... just do it.

Comment: It's because I don't know what to do that I'm here asking for your help

Comment: At stackoverflow, there's a sort of general policy of helping people who help themselves. You have to show some willingness to make an effort yourself, and this post shows no such effort. Do you already have a 'differenceInDays' function?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great opportunity to use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) feature that is a function of Javascript arrays. This function *reduces* an array down to 1 value.

The syntax looks like this:

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const sum = array.reduce(function(sumSoFar, currentElement) {
    return sumSoFar + currentElement;
}, 0 /* initial value of sumSoFar */);

console.log(sum); // 15
```

So, in your case since you've grouped items together already, the code is a bit more involved, but still not difficult. The final price could be calculated like this:

```
Object.keys(groups).reduce(function(sum, group) {
    return sum + differenceInDays(groups[group][0].Dates.To, groups[group][0].Dates.From) * groups[group][0].Items.reduce(function(subSum, item) {
        return subSum + item.RoomNum;
    }, 0);
}, 0);
```

This works because of the distributive property of multiplication that states `a * (b + c) = a * b + a * c` - we can sum the number of rooms and multiply that by the number of days, and it both is equivalent to the formula you posted and yields cleaner/shorter code.

Comment: the groups is a Dictionary<Model[]>?

Comment: group.Items.reduce(function(subSum, item),i think the 'subSum,item' is Model,not 'number'.so,Is there a missing loop？

Comment: my bad - there were a couple missing property accessors - I updated the code. One part I forgot about was that since we're reducing arrays of objects, we need to provide reduce with an initial value. By default sumSoFar is the first element of the array, and it starts iteration with the second, but you can override that by providing an initial value

Answer (score 0):

i think i need this code:

```
 private buildNightNum(
    groups: Dictionary<Model[]>,
    item: string
  ) {
    let differenceFromTo = groups[item]
      .filter(t => t.Dates)
      .reduce(
        (a, b) => a + differenceInDays(b.Dates.To, b.Dates.From),
        0
      );
    let roomNum = groups[item]
      .filter(t => t.Items.filter(s => s.RoomNum))
      .reduce(
        (a, b) =>
          a +
          b.Items.filter(s => s.RoomNum)
            .map(s => s.RoomNum)
            .reduce((c, d) => c + d, 0),
        0
      ); 
    return   differenceFromTo* roomNum ;
  }
```